# tmux, how to prevent broken pipe?

Tags: ssh, tmux

I'm new to ssh and tmux. I want to run a rake task on a remote server via ssh but I want to shutdown my computer and want the task to continue running on the server.

So I discovered tmux with seems to do that, but last night I got an `write error, broken pipe`. After I reattached the tmux session. My internet home internet is very unstable, so i may got a new IP, is that a problem?
So, how can I prevent this?

Comment: You mean the re-attach succeeded? or it failed with "write error"? Did you start tmux on your local computer or on the server?

Comment: I ran tmux on my maschine. I did: tmux; ssh server.foo; rake something; close terminal + shut down computer.

Answer (score 9):

As I understand you, you want to leave a program running on a server and the program should run within tmux. To make this work you have to run tmux on the server.

#### Step-wise

```
client$ ssh server
server$ tmux
server$ program

[detach from tmux]

server$ exit
client$
```

To reattach you can do:

```
client$ ssh server
server$ tmux attach
```

#### In one line

```
client$ ssh -t server tmux new program

[detach]
```

If you add `-d` switch to `new` the tmux session will not attach, but run in the background. Something like this:

```
client$ ssh -qt server tmux new -d "'program'"
```

Note that you need to double quote the command if it contains whitespace.

Reattach with:

```
ssh -t server tmux attach
```